# network UNCLAIMED

Tags: wireless, 16.04, ralink

```
sudo lshw -C network

       *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:63510000-6351ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 38:ea:a7:e3:ce:ee
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:63404000-63404fff memory:63400000-63403fff
```

My laptop does not show any wifi network connections. 
What is the solution for this??

output for sudo modprobe rt2800pci:

did not get anything in output for this.

wireless-info output:

```
    ########## wireless info START ##########

    Report from: 20 Aug 2016 12:13 IST +0530

    Booted last: 20 Aug 2016 00:00 IST +0530

    Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

    ##### release ###########################

    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Release:    16.04
    Codename:   xenial

    ##### kernel ############################

    Linux 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

    ##### desktop ###########################

    Ubuntu

    ##### lspci #############################

    07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
        DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE  802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Ad
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]

    08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
        DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:183e]

    ##### lsusb #############################

    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:0348 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    ##### PCMCIA card info ##################

    ##### rfkill ############################

    ##### lsmod #############################

    cfg80211              565248  0
    hp_wmi                 16384  0
    sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
    rt3290sta            1155072  0
    wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi

    ##### interfaces ########################

    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    ##### ifconfig ##########################

    eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>  
              BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
              Interrupt:16 

    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF2]>  
              inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::82d3:f25f:f057:e5c4/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:151767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:104837 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:183526108 (183.5 MB)  TX bytes:13938615 (13.9 MB)

    ##### iwconfig ##########################

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    eno1      Ralink STA  


    ##### route #############################

    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0

    ##### resolv.conf #######################

    nameserver 127.0.1.1
    search domain.name

    ##### network managers ##################

    Installed:

        NetworkManager

    Running:

    root      2455     1  0 11:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

    ##### NetworkManager info ###############

    GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
    GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
    GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
    GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
    GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
    GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
    GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF2]>
    GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
    GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
    GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
    GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:08:00.0/net/eth0
    GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
    GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
    GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
    GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
    GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
    GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
    GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
    GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       598f6bb0-a87b-45c7-9684-2aae054ef826
    GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
    GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
    CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
    CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
    CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
    WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{7}
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   598f6bb0-a87b-45c7-9684-2aae054ef826 | Wired connection 1
    IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.4/24
    IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
    IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
    IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
    IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          domain.name
    DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1471758423
    DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
    DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
    DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.4
    DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = domain.name
    DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
    DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
    DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
    DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
    IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::82d3:f25f:f057:e5c4/64
    IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::928d:78ff:fe0f:817f
    IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::928d:78ff:fe0f:817f/128, nh = ::, mt = 100

    ##### NetworkManager.state ##############

    [main]
    NetworkingEnabled=true
    WirelessEnabled=true
    WWANEnabled=true

    ##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
    dns=dnsmasq

    [ifupdown]
    managed=false

    ##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/udta_tir]] (600 root)
    [connection] id=udta_tir | type=802-11-wireless
    [802-11-wireless] ssid=udta_tir | mac-address=<MAC address>
    [ipv4] method=auto
    [ipv6] method=auto

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/aahana]] (600 root)
    [connection] id=aahana | type=802-11-wireless
    [802-11-wireless] ssid=aahana | mac-address=<MAC address>
    [ipv4] method=auto
    [ipv6] method=auto

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/mgmt_sales]] (600 root)
    [connection] id=mgmt_sales | type=802-11-wireless
    [802-11-wireless] ssid=mgmt_sales | mac-address=<MAC address>
    [ipv4] method=auto
    [ipv6] method=auto

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/kaustubh's]] (600 root)
    [connection] id=kaustubh's | type=802-11-wireless
    [802-11-wireless] ssid=kaustubh's | mac-address=<MAC address>
    [ipv4] method=auto
    [ipv6] method=auto

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/I'veseenyounaked]] (600 root)
    [connection] id=I'veseenyounaked | type=802-11-wireless
    [802-11-wireless] ssid=I'veseenyounaked | mac-address=<MAC address>
    [ipv4] method=auto
    [ipv6] method=auto

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AHVAAN-WIFI]] (600 root)
    [connection] id=AHVAAN-WIFI | type=wifi | permissions=
    [wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=AHVAAN-WIFI
    [ipv4] method=auto
    [ipv6] method=auto

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dlink]] (600 root)
    [connection] id=dlink | type=802-11-wireless
    [802-11-wireless] ssid=dlink | mac-address=<MAC address>
    [ipv4] method=auto
    [ipv6] method=auto

    ##### iw reg get ########################

    Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

    country 00: DFS-UNSET
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
        (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

    ##### iwlist channels ###################

    lo        no frequency information.

    eth0      no frequency information.

    eno1      0 channels

    ##### iwlist scan #######################

    lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

    eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

    eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

    ##### module infos ######################

    [cfg80211]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
    description:    wireless configuration support
    license:        GPL
    author:         Johannes Berg
    srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
    depends:        
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
    parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
    parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

    [rt3290sta]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/rt3290sta.ko
    version:        2.6.0.0_rev1
    srcversion:     073AC1AA84019DBCFEC8F58
    depends:        
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
    parm:           mac:rt28xx: wireless mac addr (charp)

    ##### module parameters #################

    [cfg80211]
    cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
    ieee80211_regdom: 00

    ##### /etc/modules ######################

    lp
    rt3290sta

    ##### modprobe options ##################

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
    blacklist ath_pci

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
    blacklist evbug
    blacklist usbmouse
    blacklist usbkbd
    blacklist eepro100
    blacklist de4x5
    blacklist eth1394
    blacklist snd_intel8x0m
    blacklist snd_aw2
    blacklist i2c_i801
    blacklist prism54
    blacklist bcm43xx
    blacklist garmin_gps
    blacklist asus_acpi
    blacklist snd_pcsp
    blacklist pcspkr
    blacklist amd76x_edac
    blacklist rt2800pci

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-myrt2800pci.conf]
    blacklist rt2800pci

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ralink.conf]
    blacklist rt2800pci
    blacklist rt2x00pci

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
    alias net-pf-3 off
    alias net-pf-6 off
    alias net-pf-9 off
    alias net-pf-11 off
    alias net-pf-12 off
    alias net-pf-19 off
    alias net-pf-21 off
    alias net-pf-36 off

    [/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
    blacklist microcode

    [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
    options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

    [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
    softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

    [/etc/modprobe.d/rt3290.conf]
    options rt3290 fwlps=N

    ##### rc.local ##########################

    exit 0

    ##### pm-utils ##########################

    [/etc/pm/config.d/config] (644 root)
    SUSPEND_MODULES="rt3290"

    ##### udev rules ########################

    [/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
    # PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
    SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF2]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
    # PCI device 0x1814:0x3290 (rt2800pci)
    SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

    ##### dmesg #############################

    [   41.779455] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
    [   44.592614] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
    [   44.592664] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
    [   46.139107] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
    [   46.139120] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

    ########## wireless info END ############
```

output for dmesg | grer rt3:

```
 [   15.770994] rt3290sta: module license 'unspecified' taints kernel.
 [   15.771405] rt3290sta: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

Comment: What is the exact result of the command: `sudo modprobe rt2800pci`? Please edit your question to add the result.

Comment: @chili555 it did not return any output.

Comment: @chili555

now it says:
       *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: a4:17:31:a7:bd:9f
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Comment: DISABLED usually means that the wireless switch or key combination is set to turn *off* the wireless radio. Confirm: `rfkill list all` If you see a *hard blocked:yes* then find and move that switch!

Comment: @chili555 : it says hard blocked : no

I see device not ready (firmware missing) too

Comment: Where do you see firmware missing? How about here? `dmesg | grep rt2`

Comment: I put rt3290.bin in /lib/firmware. firmware problem got fixed but now i get "device not ready" and no wifi networks are shown in drop down menu. @chili555

Comment: We need to see a full diagnostic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: @chili555. I have added the full diagnostic. please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the Broadcom driver. Your Realtek card doesn't need it and I suspect it conflicts.

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: I run the command and removed the broadcom driver and did a reboot. I still can't see my wireless connections. @chili555

Comment: Please edit your question to give an updated wireless script in place of the old. We will continue our troubleshooting.

Comment: I have updated the wireless script. Please have a look.
@chili555

Comment: You evidently installed a different driver, rt3290sta. Why? Where did you get it? Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep rt3`

Comment: I installed this driver because my network controller was 
Ralink corp. RT3290. Can you tell me which driver should i install?. @chili555

Comment: Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: After getting tired of every effort, I finally did a fresh installation of ubuntu 16.04. Now I can see the wifi networks, but the connection keeps dropping every 5 minutes. Can you help me with this issue. @chili555

Comment: If nothing else works see http://onthim.blogspot.co.ke/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html to download new drivers for the rt3290

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 16.04 for my mom on an old laptop a couple of days ago.  Wireless worked fine for 2 days then stopped working.  I checked and it's not Realtek but i was desperate and tried this command anyways it works now. Detects wireless networks just like fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.  Thanks for command.